# Is DLL right for me?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll

I have quite a bit of code that I find myself using over and over again in various applications.  I recently decided to take the time to get them all organized in one location so I can reference them from any of my solutions.  I started with a Class Library project and added a bunch of different functions and some derived controls that I use.  Some of the functions are used by the derived controls as well as being called directly from applications.  I built the project and started using the DLL in my projects.

I have a few questions regarding this custom DLL (I am using Visual C# 2010 Express):

1. The first thing I noticed is that it doesn't seem to work quite like the stock Microsoft libraries.  For instance, I can have "using System.Windows.Controls;" in a program, but I can only reference the namespace of my custom library with the using directive.  It would be nice to organize my classes in a similar fashion if it makes sense to do so.  Is it possible to have the classes nested like the Microsoft ones?

edit: For example... If I type at the top of my application code "using System.", I get a bunch of sub-namespaces to choose from.  I continue typing "Windows.", and I get more sub-categories.  If I add a reference to MyCustom.dll and start typing "using MyCustom.", I don't see any of my classes or subclasses.  I'm just asking how to organize things within my class library so they behave like the stock libraries.

1. Is it a good idea to make one big DLL file with all of my reusable code?  I don't have a ton of code at the moment, but I want to leave room for expansion.  What is the best practice for this?
2. How do I deal with my DLL when I make an installer for my applications?  I normally use InnoSetup to make my installers.
3. Here is my main concern... Say I use a function from my custom DLL in Application1 and someone installs it.  I later add some features or make a change to that function for Application2 that I am building.  If the new features break Application1 or change something in an undesirable way, what happens when a user installs Application2?  Is my custom DLL shared between the applications or does each application have its own version of my DLL?  Obviously, I would build a new version of Application1 to make it work with the new DLL, but there is no guarantee that the user would update it.

Thanks!

Comment: Please re-word question 1, I can't understand the problem you say you're experiencing.

Comment: There are entirely too many questions and not enough information here. Questions here are supposed to be short and concise, and answerable directly by a single post. You have several questions here, all of which could be answered individually. You need to break this up into several separate questions, one per post, so that it works within the design of StackOverflow. The [FAQ] has more info about how questions should be asked here. As your question is now stated, it's not answerable reasonably, and I'm going to have to vote to close as not constructive; there are just too many possible parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can have your code nested in its own sub-namespaces so-to-speak, by changing the namespace in the class file from: SomeNamespace, to: SomeNamespace.SubNamespace. Incidentally, if you do "Add -> New -> Folder" to your project in the solution explorer of Visual Studio, VS will automatically use your "nested" namespace when you do "Add -> New -> Class", which will be the name of the folder you added. So if your original namespace is: MyDLLProject, and you add a folder to the project named: HelpfulStuff, then when you add a new class file to that folder, you will see the namespace is now "MyDLLProject.HelpfulStuff", and consequently, you will need to reference it in your code that way, either by fully specifying it, or by including a "using MyDLLProject.HelpfulStuff" at the top of any class file that needs to use the code contained therein.

2) Wrapping any and all RE-USEABLE code into a DLL is certainly a good practice, as it is then easily used in other projects, and will only ever have to be changed once, if a change is required, no matter how many projects use it. If however, you can be fairly certain you will never use the code anywhere else, it may not be worth the time and effort.

3) InnoSetup should automatically include any assemblies (.NET DLL's) that are referenced by your project. you can see what DLL's are referenced, and add references from the "References" node in the project tree, in the solution explorer of VS. This is where you will need to add a reference to your own DLL, should you choose to make one.

4) Unless you actually go through the trouble of making your DLL a shared component by having it registered in the GAC (Global Assembly Cache), you will not need to worry about this. Your application will always have its own copy of the DLL's it uses, and will not step on each others toes in the way you are imagining.

Comment: Great!  Thanks for explaining the namespace thing.  I like the way that works.  I will try it out and see if it makes sense for what I do.  I will move forward with the DLL method now that I feel confident I won't have conflicts between applications.

Answer (score 1):

DLLs are great for what you are trying to do.

> 1) I can have "using System.Windows.Controls;" in a program, but I can
>   only reference the namespace of my custom library with the using
>   directive.

The reason this is is that MS exposes multiple interfaces in their DLLs.
To do this normally requires that you register more than one component in your DLL
in effect exporting your classes to the client using your code.

> 2) Is it a good idea to make one big DLL file with all of my reusable
>   code?

DLLs are generally a deployment layout. So, if you have clients that may only be interested in subsets of your code then break the code up into smaller DLLs, but its not needed unless theres a need.
It is possible to provide other dev teams with specific API components for just their needs, so that you only ship smaller grained components when you need to, the bigger the DLL and the more clients the more change has an impact on them.

> 3) How do I deal with my DLL when I make an installer for my
>   applications? I normally use InnoSetup to make my installers.

Modern installers for windows all include the ability to distribute DLLs and to register components inside your DLLs in the windows registry.

> 4) Here is my main concern...(multiple versions of the same dll across
>   deployments)

In the old days, when people deployed their DLLs to windows system folders this was a big problem.  This is no longer the case in well deployed windows applications.  Windows sandboxes DLLs to be local to the installing application automatically so even an app that thinks its installing to system32 or loading from there is truly not.  You dont have to worry about conflicts as long as you follow the rules of DLL deployment and ship your DLLs with your app and dont try to force them into system directories (which windows will likely not allow anyway

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

1. I don't understand your problem. Please re-word it.
2. It varies. Generally re-usable libraries are specific to your solution (such as a shared library containing common `enum` types, or a database model). If you just have snippets of code that you re-use in different projects it might be an idea to copy the source files into your projects, or reference a source file (VS does let you do this) without making a copy of it. Just be careful if you ever use source-control.
3. There's nothing to worry about, the DLL is just another dependency of your application. VS will (by default) copy the DLL to your application project's output directory, so you just need to configure your installer just to include all of the files in your `bin` folder (except maybe XML documentation files).
4. Unless you go to a lot of trouble to make your DLLs shared in the filesystem (which was a popular thing to do in the 1990s when HDD space was limited, see the "Microsoft Shared" folder for an example) this is not an issue because each distribution of your application will have is own copy of the shared DLL ("sharing" is at compile-time, not run-time). The .NET CLR will throw an error if an application tries to launch with an incompatible DLL file compared to the one it was compiled against (and you can enforce this further with strong-named assemblies).

Comment: Awesome.  You answered my main questions.  I wanted to make sure I wasn't going to have a bunch of conflicts or library version nightmares once I start distributing some of my applications.